# Tap gesture is not working on UIimageview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my application i have three uiimageview which is moving randomly. on single tap on imageview it should hide. But my tapgesture is not working. on single tap it is not getting hide.

```
- (void)showAlert1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (image1.tag == 1)
    {
        image1.hidden = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        image1.hidden = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)showAlert2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (image1.hidden == TRUE && image3.hidden == FALSE)
    {
        image2.hidden = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        image2.hidden = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)showAlert3:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (image1.hidden == TRUE && image2.hidden == TRUE)
    {
        image3.hidden = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        image3.hidden = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (image1.tag == 1)
    {
        image1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTargetelf actionselector(imageAlerts];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [image1 addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }

    if (image2.tag == 2)
    {
        image2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTargetelf actionselector(showAlert2];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [image2 addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }

    if (image3.tag == 3) 
    {
        image3.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTargetelf actionselector(showAlert3];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [image3 addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)showAlert1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{     
  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)     
  {        
     // your handling code
    if (image1.tag==1)
         image1.hidden=TRUE;
    else
         image1.hidden=FALSE;     
  }  
}
```

Comment: - (void)showAlert1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender. this is only not getting called when i touch on the image.

Comment: it means there is some problem in viewWillAppear.
AS I said in iOSPawan answer, there must be some problem in image.tag property check.

Comment: Use condition check something like this


 if(self.view == image1)

Answer (score 25):

Please checkmark the `userInteractionEnabled` and `multipleTouch` in xib file if you have added image in xib

or

```
image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
image.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and set in to self?

Comment: i have put the code above which i have done. Please look into it. where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
- (void)viewWillAppearBOOL:animated
{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

if (image1.tag==1)

{

image1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTargetelf actionselector(showAlert1:];

tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[image1 addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

if (image2.tag==2) 

{

image2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTargetelf actionselector(showAlert2:];

tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[image2 addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}
if (image3.tag==3) 

{

image3.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTargetelf actionselector(showAlert3:];

tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[image3 addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}
}
```

Also it has memory leak. `UIGesture` is not released after it adds to image.

Comment: no while creating tap gesture you are setting select to  imageAlerts, showAlert2, showAlert3 it should be showAlert1: , showAlert2: showAlert3:

Comment: Also i guess there is no need to check image.tag properly in view willAppear. as all images is having seperate references.

Comment: yes as @iOSPawan said, check if you are using tag property in right way